# No escribir none cuando la función quiere retornar algo

Tags: python

¿Cómo hago para que una función no me retorne nada? Es decir, yo he hecho un código que tiene un par de print los cuales pasan una función una cadenada de caracteres.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
def func(valor):
   #código función

print 'print 1',func('texto1')
print 'print 2',func('texto2')
print 'print 3',func('texto3')
```

La cosa es que la función hace todo lo que quiero y me devuelve los mensajes deseados pero tambien me devuelve un *none*, es decir que me quiere hacer un return pero no tiene nada que retornar, ¿cómo hago para que eso no salga?

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habría que ver cómo es tu función `func()`, pero de forma general debes saber que cuando una función termina sin haber retornado nada en concreto, python hace que retorne `None`. Por ejemplo esta:

```
def func(valor):
    if valor>2:
        return "Mayor de dos"
```

Si la llamas con `func(1)`, encontrarás un `None` como valor retornado.

Obviamente la solución es hacer que la función *siempre* retorne algo. Qué retornar en casos en que no hay valor adecuado depende del contexto. Si tu función por ejemplo retorna números, podrías plantearte retornar un `0` o un `-1` como indicador de que no hay solución adecuada en ese caso. Pero quizás esos valores no sean adecuados a tu problema, porque podrían confundirse con resultados reales. Por eso `None` suele ser un valor típico para indicar "no hay valor apropiado".

En tu caso, ya que aparentemente usas el resultado sólo para imprimirlo, podrías retornar una cadena vacía. Así:

```
def func(valor):
    if valor>2:
        return "Mayor de dos"
    return ""
```

En ese caso el `print` no mostraría nada. Pero puede que ésta tampoco sea una buena solución, dependiendo del caso. Si por ejemplo la función suele retornar números, pero decides retornar `""` en caso de que no haya un valor apropiado de retorno, puedes causar confusión a quien use tu función, ya que si espera un número quizás luego quiera operar con él (por ejemplo sumarle otro), cosa que no podrá hacer si el resultado es `""`.

La solución más general sería hacer que retorne `None`, y comprobar cuando la llames si ese ha sido el caso. Por ejemplo:

```
result = func('texto1')
if result is not None:
    print 'print1', result
```

Comment: Despues de responderte me acabo de dar cuenta de que quizás has caido en un error muy común, y es que tu función en realidad no retorna nada _nunca_, sino que imprime cosas. Imprimir cosas no es lo mismo que retornarlas. Si tu función sólo contiene `print`s, deberías llamarla simplemente con `func()` y no con `print func()`  ya que en ese caso, además de los print que tenga tu función que se verán correctamente, habrá un `print`  último que imprimirá el valor retornado, que es `None`.